# Cordova File Plugin ignore my folder and files

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm trying read a file (example.json) inside www/usr/ folder, but I'm having some problems, to try see what is happening I decide list the files and folders inside of www/, and surprise, my usr/ folder is not listed, just default folder as js/, css/, img/, etc...

This code list the folders:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
        cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/',
        function (dirEntry) {
            // list folders
            function success(entries) {
                var i;
                alert(entries.length > 0);
                for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    alert(entries[i].name);
                }
            }

            var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
            directoryReader.readEntries(success,self.error);
        },
        self.error
    );
});
```

And this try get the file:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
        cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/usr/',
        function (dirEntry) {
            dirEntry.getFile(
                'example.json',
                {create: false, exclusive: false},
                function (fileEntry) {
                    alert('ok');
                },
                self.error
            );
        },
        self.error
    );
});
```

Did I do someting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Does the usr folder contain data already or are you trying to read a file that the app is creating at runtime?

Comment: The example.json is not created at runtime